# Quick release saddle bolts?

Tags: saddle, security

I need to find a way to easily remove the saddle on my folding bike.

Solutions from Zefal (Lock & Roll) or [Pitlock](http://www.pitlock.com/)/[PinheadComponents](http://www.pinheadcomponents.com/)/[AntiVandale](http://www.vis-antivandale.com/) aren't usable because they're meant for regular bikes, where adjusting the saddle is uncommon once set, while folders require adjustment every time the bike is folded/unfolded.

I was wondering if some company made a quick-release [saddle bolt](http://technology.open.ac.uk/materials/mem/images/images_cc/ccf14_2r.jpg), so that I could easily take the saddle with me and leave the seat post.

That doesn't prevent some ass*e to take the seatpost just "for fun", but it reduces the risk and it's a lighter alternative (seat posts on folders are bigger and heavier than on standard bikes).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have an exact replacement, but this website has all manner of hardware including cam levers with metric threading: http://www.mcmaster.com/#cam-levers/=n8bs5o ... you may be able to find something appropriate.

Comment: Got a reply from McMaster-Carr: "Due to the complexity of U.S. export regulations, McMaster-Carr accepts international orders only from our established customers. This decision also applies to orders shipping within the United States, because it is based on the final destination of the items. We will not provide a quotation or accept your orders. "

Comment: I take it you're not in the US...bummer.

Comment: There's http://www.bikefit.com/p-52-switchit-rapid-saddle-changertilt-adjuster.aspx but it's hellish bulky and expensive for everyday use, rather than its design purpose of swapping saddles for a bike fit.

Comment: More usefully, maybe you could do something along the lines of  http://www.pdeleuw.de/fahrrad/birdy2e.html#sattel
(Cable attached to saddle in a way that allows the seatpost to go up and down, but not be removed. Useless if your thief has cable cutters, but deters casual vandalism.)

Comment: And not exactly what you are looking for, and no sign of international shipping, but might be useful to someone else looking at this question - lockable seatpost quick release: 
http://www.saveyourseatlock.com/benefits.html

Comment: Does it have to be a QR saddle bolt or can it be something more general?  For example: a way to keep your folding bike's seat safe from theft; a way to quickly/easily readjust the fore/aft/angle of your seat;  a more convenient (smaller, lighter) way of keeping a folding bike's seat with you when you leave it alone;  a way to easily share the same saddle across multiple bikes that have different seatpost diameters.

Comment: @OverTheRainbow This sounds like you are getting tired of resetting the height on the seat each time you unfold it or some other optimization you are trying to perform?

Comment: @OverTheRainbow I just saw a pic of an old [Campagnolo Euclid seatpost](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cycling-/7294/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=campagnolo+euclid+seatpost) that seems to basically have a QR seatpost binder bolt set up as the rail clamp binder!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your hex seatbolt with a knobbed or winged bolt of the same strength and sizing specifications.

Clamping knob: [image: Clamping knob]

Wing screw:
[image: Wing screw]

(I happened to see these at http://www.jwwinco.com/products/section8/, but do not know if they are up to spec. @WTHarper mentioned the [McMaster-Carr](http://www.mcmaster.com/#thumb-screw-fasteners/=o5jl6s) site that has lots of options.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried any of these suggestions myself.  You may want to look into a seatpost that is just a tube, and a seat clamp that, itself, clamps to the seat tube.  All these ideas depend on sourcing parts that fit your seat tube diameter, of course:

1. Use the old style [seatpost that ends in a nub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AO9LB0).  Attach your saddle to [an old style saddle clamp](http://www.beachbikes.net/products/Saddle-Clamp-Black-813.html?gclid=COqv_tP9-LgCFWyCQgod50AAsA).  Replace the bolt on the saddle clamp with some quick-release bolt or winged/knobbed bolt.  The saddle and clamp might separate on loosening and removal, however.
2. See if a [removable seatpost head clamp](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/ritchey/stubby-scott-addict-seat-clamp-ec008998) would attach to a nub-ended seat tube.  Maybe you'd have to saw the end of a seat tube that fits, and find a removable seatpost head clamp that fits the correct diameter.  The advantage with this is that the head would clamp to your saddle separately from clamping to the seat tube.  Perhaps modify the clamp so that it is quick-release by adding your own QR collar or replacing a bolt.  These types seem to be related to "integrated" seatposts.  [Another one](http://clee-cycles.co.uk/esite/P1092/product).  Also, search for [Cannondale Synapse seatpost clamp](http://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=950d877744f5157c&q=cannondale+synapse+seatpost+clamp+).

Answer (score 0):

Skip the bolt and hold the seat rail clamp to the seatpost with [locking pliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locking_pliers) (aka "Vise Grips").
[image: locking pliers]

Comment: My first reaction was to flag this as not a real answer, then I laughed and realized it probably was.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I recall a radio ad for Vice Grips from about 40 years ago where (supposedly) an emergency repair was made on a race car by clamping Vice Grips to the steering column, after the steering wheel came off.  And I wouldn't doubt that things very much similar have been done in real life.

Comment: What we do in emergencies isn't always a good idea to do every day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your goal is to prevent the saddle from being stolen or getting wet. But if your are just trying to secure the seat one of these would do the trick. 
http://ecom1.planetbike.com/2024.html

You can buy fancy saddle cover or just use a plastic shopping bag to keep it dry.

I you simply enjoy carrying your saddle around these options may not help.