# Bike seat and post recommendation

Tags: mountain-bike

Yesterday someone stole my bike seat along with the seat post. I am planning to buy a new seat with post that fits it. My bike is a Bulls Pulsar mountain bike. I have found a seat on Amazon but I have not found a seat post that would fit this seat. I request for your help. Thanks.

https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07DB3KVPS/

and this is my bike:

https://www.radonline.de/bulls-pulsar-street-21-gang-kettenschaltung-herrenfahrrad-trekking-modell-2018-26-zoll-schwarz-matt.html

Comment: It's a totally normal saddle with a separate additional attachment to suit other posts. see here https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56352/is-it-possible-and-safe-to-attach-this-type-of-seat-to-suspension-seatpost/56353#56353

Comment: The saddle you linked to comes with a clamp that fits candle style post. Best to just ignore that part and get a seat post with an integrated clamp.

Answer (score 6):

You need a "seat post" which has to be exactly the same diameter as the old one.

The specs page only says "Seat post: STYX aluminum" which is not enough information.

Your best option would be to close the clamp to its normal position, and measure the internal diameter of the frame using calipers.  A ruler won't be accurate enough, because while common seatposts could be in these sizes:

- 25.4 mm
- 26.2 mm
- 26.8 mm
- 27.2 mm
- 28.6 mm
- 31.2 mm etc

It is not impossible for the seatpost to be some weird in-between size.

The overall length of the seatpost is less important, only that it is long-enough.

You'll also need a seatpost with an integrated clamp at the top, or a separate clamp.  Very likely whatever you buy will have a clamp included.

---

Separately - someone has stolen your bike seat once already.  Expect that it will happen again.  Some relevant links to protect your parts:

- [Protecting quick-release seats and wheels from theft](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/protecting-quick-release-seats-and-wheels-from-theft/)
- [Quick release saddle bolts?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16275/quick-release-saddle-bolts/)

Comment: 30.9 and 31.6 are very common MTB sizes, there is also 34.9 (Used by Scott for years).

Answer (score 1):

The 2020 model of the Pulsar Street uses an 31.6mm seatpost according to the [Bulls website](http://bulls.de/produkt/bulls-pulsarstreet-522-35037?sku=522-35037_ZEG). It will most likely be the same for your 2018 model.